# Optaplanner: problems with InverseRelationShadowVariable

Tags: optaplanner

have a many-1 relationship pupil-formGroup: pupils are assigned to a formGroup and a formGroup can contain many pupils.  I have attempted to implement an InverseRelationShadowVariable having watched your video/tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ENKHGBMDaCM (which does not quite correspond with the latest optaplanner documentation I realise)

FormGroup extracts

```
@Entity
@PlanningEntity 
public class FormGroup { 

    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "formGroup")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "formGroup", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Pupil> pupilList = new ArrayList<Pupil>();

    public List<Pupil> getPupilList() {
      return pupilList;
     }

    public Integer getPupilCount() {
      return pupilList.size();
     }
```

Pupil extracts

```
@Entity
@PlanningEntity
public class Pupil 

 @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "formGroupRange")
 @ManyToOne
 private FormGroup formGroup;
```

Config extracts

```
   <solutionClass>org.acme.optaplanner.domain.Plan</solutionClass>
   <entityClass>org.acme.optaplanner.domain.Pupil</entityClass>
   <entityClass>org.acme.optaplanner.domain.FormGroup</entityClass>
```

I believe I've followed the steps in the videoexactly (don't we all say that) but at solve time I get hundreds of errors... Repetitions of the following

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:728)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:774)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:178)

Any hint gratefully received...

Answer (score 2):

The `InverseRelationShadowVariable` creates a bi-directional relationship between the genuine planning entity (`Pupil`) and the planning value (`FormGroup`). This may become problematic if you re-use your planning domain classes for other purposes, such as ORM persistence or serialization.

In this case, Jackson is unable to serialize Pupil, because it references a FormGroup, which has a List containing a reference back to that Pupil. See? An endless loop.

Solve this issue by adding the `@JsonIgnore` annotation on top of your inverse relation property and breaking that loop for Jackson:

```java
@Entity
@PlanningEntity 
public class FormGroup { 

    @JsonIgnore // THIS IS THE FIX
    @InverseRelationShadowVariable(sourceVariableName = "formGroup")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "formGroup", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Pupil> pupilList = new ArrayList<Pupil>();

    public List<Pupil> getPupilList() {
      return pupilList;
    }

    public Integer getPupilCount() {
      return pupilList.size();
    }
...
```